# Pass variable to grep command

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I want to pass a variable in my `grep` command in Linux bash script. Variable is a text file from Internet and i want to find some words in it.

I have tried the following command in my bash:

1. `cat "$var" | grep -Po '(?<=\d[a-zA-Z]).*\..*(?=[a-zA-Z]\d)'`
2. `echo "$var" | grep -Po '(?<=\d[a-zA-Z]).*\..*(?=[a-zA-Z]\d)'`
3. `grep -Po '(?<=\d[a-zA-Z]).*\..*(?=[a-zA-Z]\d)' <<< "$var"`

but i dont get a right Result.
How can i do it?

Here is my bash:

```
#!/bin/sh    
urltext=$(curl -s https://example.com)
string=$(grep -Po '(?<=\d[a-zA-Z]).*\..*(?=[a-zA-Z]\d)' "$urltext" | tr '.' '\n' )
cat $string
```

Comment: edit you question to include something like `var="my text string"` OR `var=aFileName.txt`. You do understand the difference between `echo` and `cat`? Good luck.

Comment: What is the value of `var`, and how do you expect `grep` to use its value (i.e., what is the expected output)?

Answer (score 0):

What's supposed to be contained in the variable ?

It's a file ?

```
grep <options> <expression> "$var"
```

It's a string ?

```
echo "$var"|grep <options> <expression>
grep <options> <expression> <(echo "$var")
```

NB : try `-e` option if there are several lines in $var

Comment: Using the `echo` to pass the string in still outputs the information to console.  Isn't there a way to do this without having that output?

Comment: Yes, you can add `>/dev/null` after the command to redirect standard output to null.